# How to check if a type is an Option in FSharp Compiler Service?

Tags: f#

```
let foo = None
```

In the above example, is there a way in FSharp or FSharp Compiler Services to determine if `foo` is an `Option` type without resorting to reflection?

I tried the following function but I'm getting a `System.InvalidOperationException: 'the type 'obj' does not have a qualified name'`  error when accessing the `fsharpType.TypeDefinition.FullName` property in the code below.

```
let private isOptionType (fsharpType:FSharpType) =    
    if fsharpType.HasTypeDefinition then    
        let fullnme = fsharpType.TypeDefinition.FullName
        match fsharpType.TypeDefinition.TryFullName with
        | Some fullName -> (Type.GetType fullName).GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Option<_>>
        | None -> false
    else
        false

let private checkOptionType (checkFile:FSharpCheckFileResults) = fun () ->   
    let partialAssemblySignature = checkFile.PartialAssemblySignature    
    let moduleEntity = partialAssemblySignature.Entities.[0]
    let fnVal = moduleEntity.MembersFunctionsAndValues.[0]
    isOptionType fnVal.FullType
```

Comment: How are you calling that function? Please post a minimal complete example.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've updated the question with a minimal complete example. thanks.

Comment: Ok, are you sure you're looking at that definition and not some other one? Could you try printing out its name before looking at its type?

Comment: fsharpType is of type `FSharpType` ( https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-compiler-docs/reference/fsharp-compiler-symbols-fsharptype.html ) and I couldn't see how to get it's type name without accessing the `TypeDefinition` property.

Comment: Not the type name. The name of `fnVal`

Comment: FullName property of `fnVal` returns TmpD83E.foo and CompiledName returns foo. not sure if these are the ones you meant by name though.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problem. Can you try changing the line with `foo` to `let foo = Some 42`?

Comment: Actually the real error is `"InvalidOperationException: option'1 doesn't have a qualified name"` in both cases `None` and `Some 42`, I don't know why I was getting `obj` before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the F# `option` type, as understood by the F# Compiler Service, does not have a qualified name, but I can confirm that I get the same error when I tried to do this.

That said, I think you can reconsider how you detect whether a type is `option`. Your approach is to get a fully qualified name and then see if this matches the name of `option` that is in the F# library running the compiler service. I suppose that could work, but equally, you can just check the name as string:

```
let isOptionType (fsharpType:FSharpType) =    
  fsharpType.HasTypeDefinition &&
  fsharpType.TypeDefinition.Namespace = Some "Microsoft.FSharp.Core" &&
  fsharpType.TypeDefinition.CompiledName = "option`1"
```

If you wanted something more robust, then I think the best option would be to use the F# compiler service to type check a minimal code snippet with just `"let x = None"`, extract the type of the `x` variable, save this and then, when you need to check whether something else is an option type, compare the type definition of that with the type definition of the type of `x`.

For reference, I took the [code sample from the F# Compiler Service docs](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-compiler-docs/fcs/symbols.html) and added the following:

```
let file = "/home/user/Test.fsx"
let input = "let x = None"

let parseFileResults, checkFileResults = 
  parseAndTypeCheckSingleFile(file, SourceText.ofString input)

let partialAssemblySignature =  
  checkFileResults.PartialAssemblySignature

let typ = 
  partialAssemblySignature.Entities.[0].
    MembersFunctionsAndValues.[0].FullType

isOptionType typ // Returns 'true'
```

Comment: "...but I can confirm that I get the same error when I tried to do this..." -> does this mean it's a bug in FCS? I'm happy to file an issue in github

Comment: `fsharpType.TypeDefinition.CompiledName` returns `obj` instead of "option`1" meaning it doesn't work either?

Comment: Yes it does. Try `let foo = Some 42`

Comment: The code I posted worked for me with `let x = None`. I included more complete example in the answer. I do not think this is a FSC bug - I think it is just the nature of the built-in `option'1` type.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin but None is a correct instantiation of `Option<'a>` too

Comment: @TomasPetricek because you added "open FSharp.Core" before "let foo = None" right?

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin @knocte Yes, I tried the code above (with the necessary initialization copied from the docs) and it behaves as I descriped (`CompiledName` returns `option'1`). I'm using FSC version 38.0.2 in F# interactive 11.3.2.0. Maybe it is a version issue?